# Using string instead of SecureString in constructor

Tags: c#, security

I have a class which stores a password internally in a SecureString field. To my understanding this can protect this field from being written in logs, dump, etc. Since sometimes(...always) I use this class with static credentials I am thinking of creating additional constructor taking string instead of SecureString and generate the password value in the constructor.

```
    public Credentials(string username, SecureString password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Credentials(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = new SecureString();
        // Creating the secure string
        Array.ForEach(password.ToCharArray(), this.password.AppendChar); ;
    }
```

So my question is: given that the password is already available somewhere as a string, is creating this constructor and passing a string variable creating any additional security risks?

Comment: The original string will be held in memory as they're immutable.

Comment: Using SecureString correctly is difficult and increasingly unlikely since there just isn't much unmanaged code around anymore that can use Marshal.SecureStringToXxxx().  And yes, complete fail whale in this snippet, the *password* argument to the constructor flubs it.  So don't use it, a false sense of security is a lot worse then no security.  At least now you know you need a door and a lock and a secure way to discard the disk drive.